# C# - Get ISO 639-2 three-letter code from language name and country name

Tags: c#, globalization, cultureinfo, regioninfo

### The problem

I've got the following information:

- *Language name*
- *Country*

**An example would be:** `English`, `United States`

This information needs to be **converted into an ISO 639-2 three-letter code**.
It might be good to know that I'm using dotnet 6 with C# 10.

### What I looked at so far

So far, I tried using the `CultureInfo`. Sadly, `CultureInfo` does not take a language and a country. I'm aware of the `RegionInfo` class, but from my understanding, it does not contain a mapping for all countries and it requires as an input something like "en-US" which I do not have.

Comment: you'll likely have to store a map of that

Comment: Language and Country are 2 different things.  Even if you wanted to loosely say CultureInfo is similar to Language, and RegionInfo is similar to Country, you would need to map them together.  Eastern Canada may prefer French, whereas Western Canada may prefer English (some UK English over US English).

Comment: Besides `en-CA` English Canada and `fr-CA` French Canada, there are examples of Spanish versus Spain.  A different version of Spanish is spoken in Span than in Mexico.  Even within Spain, their are regional differences.  Barcelona speaks as much Catalan `ca-ES` than Spanish `es-ES`.

Comment: As a solution you can use CultureInfo.GetCultures() and then compare its properties with your inputs. Although if you want the best solution I think you should search for implementation of ISO 639 and ISO 3166 in .Net which has full language and countries name and its abbreviation in two or three letter.